# Which algorithm do you recommend for practical use to generate unique passwords for each website?

Tags: algorithm

So, in my imagination there is this simple algorithm with only one master password, let's say a prime number 'p', which I have to remember. Using only the address of the website and p, the algorithm must generate a unique password. It must be at least almost impossible to guess the value of p even if you know the algorithm. Also impossible to guess the password of website B if you know the password of website A and the algorithm. The reason why I need this algorithm: I'd have different passwords and would have to remember only one number. There's also the matter of having multiple accounts on the same website but I think it will be easy to modify the algorithm. I think it will be useful for many users.

Comment: Is it a 42-digit prime number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a use for [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).  It is a standard that augments cryptographically-strong hashes (like SHA1) with the ability to accept a "key" along with the data to hash.  In reality, it often just changes the hash's initial state to the key, rather than a known constant (such as zero.)

Under usual cryptographic assumptions, the resulting hash is only recoverable if the attacker possess the key as well as the data to hash.

Here, your master password becomes the key, and the site's domain name (or other arbitrary label) is what is hashed.  The result is your per-site password.

Answer (score 1):

This would basically be encryption, wouldn't it? You have one master key, you encrypt the name of the website, and the resulting cyphertext becomes your password.

This would actually be vulnerable if people could get a copy of your passwords - multiple cyphertexts that are known to use the same key make it much easier to analyze. And having known plain-text (the name of the website) also makes it easier to analyze/break.

Comment: The first vulnerability can be reduced, if you derive a salt from the address (say, a CRC32 checksum of it) itself. The other one can only be helped with a secure store.